# C++ example for using WIndows::System::Launcher class member functions in a console C++ app

Tags: namespaces, launcher, c++-cx

I want to make use of the member functions of the "Launcher class" [Launcher class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.Aspx) from a console C++ application, NOT a windows store app ( instead in a console application EXE).

Unlike any general WIndows API which  includes a DLL, a header file as a minimum requirement, it includes a namespace Windows::System and a meta data "Windows.winmd".

So it means it uses .NET framework (Common language runtime) for this the Launcher class in thenamesapce WIndows.System.

I changed the VS settings in Properties -> Configuration -> COmmon Language runtime suspport to include CLR.

and I'm using :

```
using namespace System;
```

But I see Launcher class isn't present here.
Also i tried

```
using namespace Windows.System;
```

as Launcher class is in WIndows.System namespace but couldn't find Launcher class here too.

Can I please ask for a help with a code snippet for using Launcher class member functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't think this could be done initially, but it does appear to be possible.

Sridhar Poduri put together a Visual Studio extension that creates a C++/CX Console application project template. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e9210454-c1b5-4d89-b8ca-92a64dfb8d28
A project built from this template will be capable of calling into C++/CX APIs such as Windows::System::Launcher::LaunchURIAsync(). However I'm not sure if this particular API can be used from a command line application, when I tried it it raised an exception.

If you want to know how to change a normal Win32 Console Application template to use C++/CX change the following in your project settings.
Under C/C++->General

1. Set "Consume Windows Runtime Extension" to "Yes /ZW"
2. Add these paths to "Additional #using directories": "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\12.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral;%(AdditionalUsingDirectories)"

Under C/C++->Code Generation

3. Set "Enable Minimal Rebuild" to "No /Gm-"

Making these changes should allow you to compile code that uses C++/CX APIs. Here is some sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace Platform;

int main(Platform::Array<Platform::String^>^ args)
{
    Platform::Details::Console::WriteLine("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

Also, I just wanted to point out that the Launcher API you are referencing is definitely not C++\CLI. It is C++\CX which shares similar syntax to C++\CLI.